# How to get HTML element value which is a attribute value of another HTML element?

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, domxpath

I am extracting value of an HTML element attribute. but that attribute itself contains another HTML element inside it. So is there anyway i can extract the HTML element value from that attribute?

Here's the element

```
<div data-content="<i>10%</i><b>C</b>"></div>
```

and I am trying to get value which is inside `<b>C</b>` i.e. C

I have tried the below xpath:

```
//div/@data-content
```

Please help is there anyway.

Comment: The XML isn't valid, so any XPath arguments won't resolve correctly. Attributes can't contain XML special characters `<`

Comment: Even if you have a well-formed XML like `<div data-content="&lt;i>10%&lt;/i>&lt;b>C&lt;/b>"></div>` the value of `data-content` attribute is going to be just characters, thus you need to use string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a typo in your XML. I assume it's supposed to be:

```
  <div data-content="<i>10%</i><b>C</b>"></div>>
```

if so, try this and see if it gets you there:

```
substring-after((//div/@data-content),'<b>')
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @HitendraSinghRathore Glad to hear it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, your input sample is not well-formed XML so the standard XPath or XSLT processing chain where an XML parser is used to parse the XML input is not going to work.

However, some XSLT or XPath processors allow you to plug in an HTML parser instead of an XML parser into the processing chain and that way you can parse the initial input and the attribute value as well to use XPath.

Furthermore, with XSLT 2 and 3 you can use David Carlisle's HTML parser implementation done in pure XSLT 2 https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/blob/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl from any XSLT 2 or later stylesheet to parse HTML you have as a string, so either passed in as a string parameter or being escaped in a CDATA section in an XML input or read in using `unparsed-text`.

Using the features of that HTML parser then allows you to call its `htmlparse` function twice and select the `b` element with e.g. `dpc:htmlparse($html-input, '', true())/div[@data-content]/dpc:htmlparse(@data-content, '', true())/b` or its content with e.g. `dpc:htmlparse($html-input, '', true())/div[@data-content]/dpc:htmlparse(@data-content, '', true())/b/string()`.

Full XSLT stylesheet would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dpc="data:,dpc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

    <xsl:param name="html-input" as="xs:string"><![CDATA[<div data-content="<i>10%</i><b>C</b>"></div>]]></xsl:param>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template" match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="dpc:htmlparse($html-input, '', true())/div[@data-content]/dpc:htmlparse(@data-content, '', true())/b/string()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online demos at

- https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3s/4
- https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3s/5

If you are tied to PHP and its XPath 1.0 support, then you at least have the ability to run XPath 1.0 extended by PHP functions against a DOMDocument created with `loadHTML` from an HTML string:

```
$html = <<<EOT
<div data-content="<i>10%</i><b>C</b>"></div>
EOT;

$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
$domDoc->loadHTML($html);


function parseXmlFragment($fragment) {
    $docFrag = $fragment[0]->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
    $docFrag->appendXML($fragment[0]->textContent);
    return $docFrag;
}

$xpath = new DOMXPath($domDoc);

$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");

$xpath->registerPHPFunctions("parseXmlFragment");

echo $xpath->evaluate("string(php:function('parseXmlFragment', //div[@data-content]/@data-content)/b)", $domDoc);
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php.